# Is it possible to use the =NOW function but only have the cell update if a specific cell is updated?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of contacts in a spreadsheet down the column, across the rows I was hoping to use `=NOW` in a cell and a name in the next cell of the last person in my team to contact them.

Is it possible to to have the `=NOW` cell only update the date and time when the name in the adjacent cell is updated?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible: every time something changes in your worksheet, a new calculation will be performed.

What you want, can only be achieved using VBA, using a `Worksheet_Changed` event (or something like that), while checking the target of that event being the cell, adjacent of the one where you need the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to avoid VBA by using iterative calculations as [explained in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28182154).

It relies on circular references and additional cells to discover when a cell has changed.